# Numpy Concatenate two list with different shapes in two dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

I have two list: `a` with shape (2, 4, 5) and `b` with shape (2, 5).

How can I concatenate them together to be (2, 4, 5) + (1, 2, 5) and then using vstack to get a list of (10, 5). Essentially I want to stack the last dimension with length 5.

I found the only way is to append b to a, then numpy.vstack

Is this something I can't do with numpy.concatenate?

Comment: A (2,1,5) can be joined to a (2,4,5) to make a (2,5,5).  That in turn can be reshaped to (10,5).  The basic point is that `concatenate` (and all the `stacks`) can only join on one dimension - all the others have to match.  The logic should be straight forward.  All the `stack` functions, including `np.append` use `np.concatenate`.

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks for the comment! But your method only works because they both have 2 in the shape. My question is to stack on the last dimension no matter the shapes in other dimensions, so generally it should work with (x,y, 5) and (z, 5).

Comment: what's the result supposed to be in that general x,y,z case?

Comment: @hpaulj It should come in the shape of ( x * y + z, 5)

Comment: Then reshape the first array to (x*y, 5)